# jQuery replace text format

Tags: jquery, json, replace

I am wanting to remove () and spaces from a field that comes from JSON

what I thought of doing was this,

```
'+myleads.Phone.replace(/(/g,'')+'
```

But I found out I would have to do it over and over again for each replace

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the RegExp to remove all opening and closing round brackets, space symbols and hyphens at once:

```
myleads.Phone.replace(/[-()\s]/g, '');
```

*EDIT:* In case you don't need to remove hyphens, change it to

```
myleads.Phone.replace(/[()\s]/g, '');
```